# Get Text of selected dropdown which is dynamically created and updated, and insert result into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

sort of confusing to explain but I have a 'select' dropdown that doesn't exist on page load, and I need to take the selected text value of it when it does exist, and display it into a div on the page. My jquery is as follows:`

```
var conceptName = $('select[name="ShippingSpeedChoice"]').find(":selected").text();
$('select[name="ShippingSpeedChoice"]').on("change", "paste", function(){$('.valss').html('+conceptName+');
});
```

`Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's not working at the moment?

Comment: the selected option text is not showing up in the div ('valss')...id like it to be the text string and not the value of the selected item btw..

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're after? (I've guessed your HTML structure from your description)

http://jsfiddle.net/zxGae/

I've simulated dynamically adding the `<select>` and rearranged your `.on` as I had no idea what `paste` was for:

```
$(document).on("change", 'select[name="ShippingSpeedChoice"]', function (e) { ... });
```

Comment: `<script id="listTemplate" type="html/template">` Nice, never seen this before. Very neat. You should add your jsFiddle code to your answer otherwise people get funny about it.

Comment: @jammykam added the major change to the answer, good advice. That's the neatest way I've seen of doing client-side templates. `type=html/template` (I've also seen `text/template`) is essentially foolproof to have it ignored from processing cross-browser. Having it in a script tag allows .innerHTML to be used neatly too.

Comment: I Googled it after you added it, very useful for adding reusable code blocks. I'll use this next time rather than lots of `append()` statements! :)